# Cutting a 250000 value long vector into pieces of 50 and summing them with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset (which is an hdf5 file) that contains a list of 250000 values, all quite small (sub 10). I want to cut this into 5000 pieces, so 50 each, and I want to individually sum the values in each of these 5000 pieces. I then want to create a histogram of these 5000 pieces, so I need to store them as well.

I am trying to do this using [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), as my very limited programming skills have been developed using this, and it seems suitable for these purposes. Now, I haven't gotten very far, but what I have done so far is:

```
for n = 1:50:249951
    % CR check before (before pumping?)
    ROdata = h5read('hdf5file', '/data', [n], [n+49]);
    sum(ROdata)
end
```

Of course, this does not yet store the values of the sum for each n. But more importantly, it does not work. For n = 1, all is fine, and I get the correct value. But already for n = 51, (so summing 51-100), I do not get the correct sum. What's going wrong here?

How should I store these (not working) sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

I assumed you already read your data and you have a `250000x1` vector.

```
%example data
data = randi(42,1,250000);

% rearranges your vector in groups of 50
A = reshape(data,[],5000);

% sums every column of your reshaped vector
sums = sum(A,1);
hist(sums,5000)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is almost exactly what I was looking for. The only thing is that your script puts them in 50 groups of 5000, rather than 5000 groups of 50. But that was easily changed! There's just so many built in functions in matlab, basically everything can be done in a few lines!

Comment: of course I misread this, changed it. If it answered your question, please accept the answer :)